# Handling an adding new item event in Sitefinity dynamic module

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I'm working with Sitefinity CMS. I've created new dynamic module with Module Builder (for example Products). I would like to do some actions when I add new item to content Products. Is it possible to handle that event?

I will be very grateful to someone who will help with suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

the most recent release of sitefinity contains some event hooks to which you can subscribe to do exactly this.

I'm still exploring this topic and some new docs should be out soon but in the meantime you want to be looking at the Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.EventHub.Subscribe(handler) where T is the type of event you want to subscribe to (Inheriting from IEvent), and handler is your event handler containing the code you wish to execute.

like I said more info is coming soon, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction in the meantime!

hope this is helpful!